# com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect and phonegap-plugin-push not working together

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building new Cordova app and can not make to work together `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect` and `phonegap-plugin-push` plugins.

Here is `cordova run` output:

```
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileLint
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preDebugBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:checkDebugManifest
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preDebugTestBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugAidl
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeDebugAssets
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugResValues
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processDebugManifest
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugSources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugJar
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugNdk
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugLocalJar
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidComPhonegapPluginsFacebookconnectFacebookLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJava
C:\workspace\myApp\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\GCMIntentService.java:390: error: cannot find symbol
            mBuilder.setColor(iconColor);
                    ^
  symbol:   method setColor(int)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 27.011 secs

c:\workspace\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "c:\workspace\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b c:\workspace\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm
 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

From https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/51 I understant that `facebookconnect` uses `android-support-v4.jar` which conflicts with `android-support-v13.jar` from `phonegap-plugin-push`. 
I have tried to remove/replace `android-support-v*.jar` as suggested but that does not help.

Cordova version: 5.2.0

phonegap-plugin-push version: 1.2.0

com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect version: 0.11.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE

This solution does not work with latest `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect` plugin.
I replaced Facebook plugin with [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) fork. It uses v4 Android library and does not conflict with `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin.

---

Finally with some help in other forums I was able to make it work!

Here is what I did:

1. Remove
   `\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\platforms\android\FacebookLib\libs\android-support-v4.jar`
   file
2. Copy `\plugins\phonegap-plugin-push\src\android\libs\android-support-v13.jar` file to `\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\platforms\android\FacebookLib\libs\`
3. Open `\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\platforms\android\FacebookLib\build.gradle` file in text editor (use Notepad++ or any other new-lines friendly editor)
4. Under the dependencies block, replace `support-v4` with `support-v13`. It should look like this:

   `dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:[20,21)'
       compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
   }`
5. Delete `\platforms\android\build\` folder and compile project with `cordova build`

*All paths are related to Cordova project's root.*

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. I am facing the exact same issue, and I believe you are on the right track, but still can't get this to work. Are you sure this is all you did ?

Comment: This solution was working with older Cordova and Push plugin versions. Few days ago I tried it with latest versions and it didn't work so I replaced Facebook plugin with [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) fork. It uses v4 Android library and does not conflict with Push plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much. Giving it a try

Answer (score 0):

One way will be to resolve problem through installing push plugin: `cordova-plugin-push-notification` , because it also uses `android-support-v4.jar`. Link to this version's [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-push-notification).
Run command to install:
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-push-notification`

Comment: I tried you suggestion but I still wasn't able to compile. Can't remember exact error but it still was related to `android-support-vX` file